# Keras 2.13.1 on Windows: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, keras

I'm using, on a Windows 11 Pro PC, Python 3.11 and I'm trying to import Tenserflow and Keras for this test program:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

data = load_breast_cancer()
label_names = data['target_names']
labels = data['target']
feature_names = data['feature_names']
features = data['data']
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features,labels,test_size = 0.40, random_state = 42)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(test, test_labels, batch_size=128)
classes = model.predict(test, batch_size=128)

print(loss_and_metrics)
print(classes)
```

But I receive the error in the subject, I've installed Tenserflow 2.13.0 and Keras 2.13.1 could you help to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you install tensorflow from PyPi or Conda? I'm using conda and I have installed another packet which is just available on PyPi and this reinstalled Tensorflow, since then I have this error...

Comment: I've used PyPi for the installation, I will check with Conda, thank you